# Difference between "verb(past) + こと + ある" and "verb + ている"

Tags: grammar

I always translate ている as "have verb (past participle)" when refering to resultant state.

But that current meaning can also be brought upon by past tense of verb combined together with こと and ある.

> 彼を殺している(or ある)
>
> 彼を殺したことはある

ている here is ofcourse not the progressive one, as some verbs (die, kill, open) do not have it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be completely wrong but I'm writing it anyway in the hope of learning from it.

> 彼を殺している

is simply

> I have killed him.

Whereas

> 彼を殺したことはある

sounds to me like

> I have the experience of killing him

which sounds weird, because it sounds like he can be killed multiple times.

Perhaps we could translate 彼 as boyfriend and then it would make sense as

> I have experience of killing boyfriends.

Answer (score 0):

They represent different times and states of being. I gave an example that doesn't involve killing :)

```
ている   - Ongoing action 
てある　 - Exists in a set state.
したことはある  - States an experience.

紙にかいてる　- I am writing it on a piece of paper
紙に書いてある 　- It is written on [that] peice of paper
紙に書いたことある   - I have written on a piece of paper
```